# Can pages in turn.js be assigned special page numbers?

Tags: jquery

Turn.js automatically assigns sequential page numbers (1,2,3, etc.) to the divs which it turns into pages, and provides a method to jump directly to any page using that number.

If a stack of pages is created automatically from other code (for example, blog entries in a TypePad blog, using MTEntries), one does not know what page number each of them will receive (at least until after the fact), and therefore cannot create direct links to those pages through API functions.

If turn.js allows a "substitute", "custom" or "alias" number for the div of a page (for example, the MTEntryID of a TypePad post), one could use that special number as the way to point to that particular page within the turn.js "magazine" using scripts assigned to buttons, index lists and the like elsewhere on the same site.

#### Question

Does anyone know if this is somehow possible? I will very much appreciate your advice.

This would seem to be interesting to many, as it would overcome the built-in page numbering of turn.js.